# Is there a binary safe column type for MySQL memory tables?

Tags: mysql

Since the [`MEMORY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html) storage engine does not support `BLOB` columns, what is the recommended way to store binary data?

We want to store gzip compressed strings between 600 and 10,000 characters long. We are using MySQL 5.5.32.

Is varchar(10000) a safe alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice will be [VARBINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) data type. However, be aware of storage [requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) - you can not store too long strings within this data type (see version-specific manual page)

Answer (score 0):

you can use LONGTEXT , it is a good alternative

Comment: `LONGTEXT` is unsupported on memory tables.

Comment: `LONGTEXT` is same as `BLOB` - in table only reference is stored while data is stored on disk. That's why `LONGTEXT` also can not be used with `MEMORY` storage-engine by definition

Comment: Make sure the column is marked as 8bit, not UTF-8, to avoid tripling the storage requirements :)